# CSS end line on letter

Tags: css

I'm trying to get the text in a div with a fixed width to break on a letter instead of a word. I cant really think of a way to explain it so I made a little example. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

What happens now.

```
|Hello   |
|World!  |
```

What I want:

```
|Hello Wo|
|rld!    |
```

Comment: +1 for clear example of desired behaviour

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`word-wrap: break-word;`

As per the CSS W3 Spec:

> An unbreakable "word" may be broken at
>   an arbitrary point if there are no
>   otherwise-acceptable break points in
>   the line. Shaping characters are still
>   shaped as if the word were not broken,
>   and grapheme clusters must together
>   stay as one unit.